# Calling Web API from Web Job or use a class?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am working on creating a Web Job on Azure and the purpose is to handle some work load and perform server background tasks on my website.

My website has several Web API methods which are used by my website but I also want the Web Job to perform the same tasks as the Web API methods after they are finished.

My question is, should I get the Web Job to call this web API (if possible) or should I move the Web API code to a Class and have the Web API and also Web Job both call this class?

I just wondered what was normal practice here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you put the common logic in a dll and have them both share that library instead of trying to get the webjob to call the webapi.

I think that will be the simple way to get what you want (plus it will help you keep things separated so they can be shared - instead of putting too much logic in your webapi).

Comment: Thank you Jason, I will look into doing that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's players choice here.  Both will run on the same instance(s) in Azure if you choose to deploy them that way.  You can either reuse by dogfooding your API or reuse by sharing a class via a .dll.  We started off mixed but eventually went with the dogfooding the API as the amount of Webjobs we are using got bigger/more complex.  Here are a couple of reasons.

- No coupling to the libraries/code used by the API
- Easier to move the Web Job into its own solution(s) only dependent on the API and any other libraries we pick for it
- Almost free API testing (Dogfooding via our own Client to the API)
- We already have logging and other concerns wired up in the API (more reuse)

Both work though in reality, it really comes down to managing the dependencies and the size of app/solution is you are building.

Comment: Thanks ElvisLives, very good point regarding moving it into its own solution, especially for scalability. I plan on scaling out the web jobs in the future and using Web API would mean no restrictions and less complicated. Testing side is also a good positive. Thanks